# Dagger 2 interdependency issue

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

In my application , I am trying to create `Dagger 2` components for

1. `Context` (To use in different classes) Which is already done
2. AppUtil (requires context for network check method) Need to get this done!

I have created components and initiated from Application class.

```
    public class MyApp extends Application{

      private ContextComponent mContextComponent;
      private AppUtilComponent mAppUtilComponent;
      private NetworkComponent mNetworkComponent;

      @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            mNetworkComponent = createNetworkComponent();
            mContextComponent =  createContextComponent();
            mAppUtilComponent = createAppUtilComponent();
        }

        private AppUtilComponent createAppUtilComponent() {
                return DaggerAppUtilComponent.builder().appUtilModule(new AppUtilModule(this)).build();
        }

        public AppUtilComponent getAppUtilComponent() {
           return mAppUtilComponent;
        }

        private NetworkComponent createNetworkComponent() {
             return DaggerNetworkComponent.builder().networkModule(new NetworkModule()).build();
        }

        public NetworkComponent getNetworkComponent() {
            return mNetworkComponent;
        }

        private ContextComponent createContextComponent() {

            return DaggerContextComponent.builder().contextModule(new ContextModule(this)).build();
        }

        public ContextComponent getContextComponent(){
            return mContextComponent;
        }
    }
```

The ContextModule class is as follows

```
@Module
public class ContextModule {

    private Context mContext;

    public ContextModule(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Context component will be

```
@Singleton
@Component (modules = ContextModule.class)
public interface ContextComponent {

    void inject(AppUtils appUtils);

}
```

AppUtilModule is like

```
@Singleton
@Component (modules = AppUtilModule.class)

public interface AppUtilComponent {

   void inject(SplashActivity splashActivity);
}
```

With this AppUtilModule have modified as

```
@Module (includes = ContextModule.class)
public class AppUtilModule {

    private AppUtils mAppUtils;
    private Context context;

    @Inject
    public AppUtilModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    public AppUtils getAppUtil(){
        mAppUtils = new AppUtils(context);
        return mAppUtils;
    }
}
```

Now my AppUtils is getting context injected , which is perfectly alright.

```
public class AppUtils {

    public Context mContext;

    @Inject
    public AppUtils(Context _context){
        mContext = _context;
    }

    public boolean isNetworkConnected(){
     //Using mContext to determine Network
    }
    ... Other Utility methods which will be used throughout my application
}
```

> But now how can I make `AppUtil` as a separate Dagger component (which
>   is internally having Context as a Dependency) and inject in other classes?

---

**EDIT 1**: After making constructor injection of context into AppUtils and using AppUtil component in SplashActivity which already had Network component

> After making the AppUtil as Dagger dependency, now Project is giving
>   compile time error. Before this changes, NetworkProcessor in SplashActivity used to work
>   fine, as it was only the dependency SplashActivity had. What is that I
>   am missing/ doing wrong!

```
public class SplashActivity ....
 {

    @Inject
    public NetworkProcessor mNetworkProcessor;
    .....
    @Inject
    public AppUtils mAppUtils;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyApp.getInstance().getAppUtilComponent().inject(this);

        MyApp.getInstance().getNetworkComponent().inject(this);
    }

}
```

Error:

```
rror: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.dev.myapp.networking.NetworkProcessor cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
com.dev.myapp.networking.NetworkProcessor is injected at
com.dev.myapp.ui.activities.landing.SplashActivity.mNetworkProcessor
com.dev.myapp.ui.activities.landing.SplashActivity is injected at
com.dev.myapp.components.AppUtilComponent.inject(com.dev.myapp.ui.activities.landing.SplashActivity)
```

Comment: ok now the situation is totally different from the one before your edits...

Comment: what are `NetworkProcessor`'s dependencies?

Comment: Its having Retrofit as a component, which is used in SplashActivity

Comment: you're having a retrofit dagger component? or what kind of component are you talking about?

Comment: I mean NetworkProcessor is a component which is having Retrofit dependencies. As network is used throughout app, I have made NetworkProcessor as a Dagger component , so that it can be injected into interested classes

Comment: I think you over-complicate your Dagger setup. I made a video to help developers with Dagger. Some found it useful, so maybe you could get some ideas from there: https://youtu.be/cx6pCIbOqtI

Comment: @Vasiliy I can see only "This video is unavailable"    ... :(

Comment: Strange. Works for me. Maybe it's something about regional restrictions. In any case, you can start reading from this answer and follow the links from there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41079553/2463035

Comment: Thank You. I will go through the same...

Answer (score 1):

So a component can create multiple dependencies at once, which are usually grouped by lifetime scope (Application = whole app lifetime, Activity = activity lifetime).

So if your `AppUtils` class has the same scope as your `ContextComponent`, you can just use it to inject the AppUtils into classes that should use it, e.g. an activity:

```
public class MainActivity extens Activity {

    @Inject AppUtils appUtils;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((MyApp) getApplication()).getContextComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

after extending the ContextComponent definition to

```
@Singleton
@Component (modules = ContextModule.class)
public interface ContextComponent {

    void inject(AppUtils appUtils);

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

and you need to change `AppUtils` to use conastructor injection:

```
public class AppUtils {
    private Context mContext;

    @Inject 
    public AppUtils(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }
}
```

---

### After Question Edit 1

Dagger does not know how to create the `NetworkProcessor`-class, hence the compiler error. To make it work, you should change `NetworkProcessor` to have a constructor that is annotated with `@Inject` like you did with `AppUtils` (the second option would be creating a `@Provides` method in a dagger module, but the first solution is easier).

You did not supply the source code of `NetworkProcessor` so I'm assuming here it only needs a `Context` as a dependency.

Now that both `AppUtils` and `NetworkProcessor` have an injectible constructor that only has `Context` as an argument, Dagger can create the missing links by itself.

You don't need the `NetworkComponent` and the `AppUtilComponent`, just one Component, so delete them. Also delete the `NetworkModule` and the `AppUtilModule`. `ContextComponent` now is sufficient to inject all the dependencies into `SplashActivity`:

```
public class SplashActivity .... {

    @Inject public NetworkProcessor mNetworkProcessor;
    .....
    @Inject public AppUtils mAppUtils;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MyApp.getInstance().getContextComponent().inject(this);
    }
    //...
}
```

This works because Dagger can create the wiring code itself, since it knows how to instantiate both `AppUtils` and `NetworkProcessor`.

Comment: Already tried .By doing so, I am already getting error. Reason==> AppUtils needs Context. And Context Component needs to be created/handled before AppUtils Component.  If you have any sample for resolving this, pls update your answer

Comment: oh you need to change `AppUtils` to be use constructor injection

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and respond back. If this resolves, you will get upvote and correct answer :)

Comment: After updating with constructor injection, classes which is having previous dependency is giving errors in compile time itself. I have updated my question  :(

Comment: My intention is to keep all three modules different. So if a class needs only first component, that class can be supplied by first component. On other hand , if some class needs all 3 components, that class can be supplied with all three... I will go through your updated code. Thanks .